# Avoid polling database mysql entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

This might look like a duplicate question, but I was not able to find an exact equivalent.

My setup is a Web API that has an api call that waits till a status in the database changes to "Complete". For this currently I am polling the database every 10 seconds. I would like to avoid polling, because the status change can happen at any time between 2 seconds to as late as 180 seconds.

I am stuck in between having very small poll times thus increasing the calls to the database and having longer poll times and thus reducing the performance of the API.

Here is what I am using,

- C# Web API 2
- Entity Framework 6
- MySQL 5.6.27

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What process updates status of that database item to Complete?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx ?

Comment: @Hackerman question is about mysql, not sql server.

Comment: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html

Comment: The update is called by a windows service that calls a separate update API call in the same Web API application.

Comment: @Hackerman, thanks for the link, I will read about how we can hook this up with entity framework. But is there any open sourced equivalent for the same. I am pretty sure that we won't be interested to use Devart's dotconnect only for this feature.

Comment: I was asking because it's often better for that process to notify your api. So when service changed status to Completed in database it sends a message to your web api (via some message broker like RabbitMQ or MSMQ) and you don't need to poll database.

Comment: @Evk, that makes sense to have a messaging framework, we already use RabbitMQ in one of our process and there is an ongoing debate to push updates as well via RabbitMQ, I will add these to the discussion as well. Thanks